# IOS: making a custom bar button but still need border for IOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm developing an app that needs to support both IOS 6 and 7. I've created a custom button and it looks great in IOS 7. However, for IOS 6 it's missing the border that you see on most buttons. I had to create the button using UIButtonTypeCustom because I needed a background image and some text overlaid. Is there a way to get the border back for IOS 6? Here's my code and a screenshot of what it looks like currently in IOS 6.

```
UIImage *commentsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"commentIcon"];
UIButton *commentsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

CGRect frame = commentsButton.frame;
frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 27);
commentsButton.frame = frame;
[commentsButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.story.commentCount] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
commentsButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[commentsButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 6, 0)];
[commentsButton setBackgroundImage:commentsImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[commentsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(comments) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *commentsBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:commentsButton];
```

[image: Navigation bar]

It doesn't  look bad but I'd like it to be a little more uniform.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are setting the background image to be your custom comments image.

Usually you would create a resizable background image which imitates a borders, and set this to be the background image.

In you case I would recommend subclassing UIButton and doing the following:

Setting the background image to be a resizable border image.
Set the image as the comments image.
Add your own UILabel and setting the text to whatever number you need.

This is what I would do.
Sorry, I don't have the time to be much more in depth, but perhaps somebody else may answer with more detail.

Comment: Sounds like a decent solution. I was really hoping to not have to resort to making a background image for the borders.